# Using Apache CXF with Aegis databinding and JAX-WS front-end

Tags: web-services, jax-ws, aegis

I'm new to the web services. Trying to learn something related to Apache CXF. Can anyone please give me an example (along with configuration, so that it can run on any application server say Tomcat) that uses Aegis data binding with JAX-WS as front-end?

I.e. the web service should use Aegis data binding with JAX-WS as front-end. The web service client may use any binding, any front-end, or it may be a simple standalone application also.

Comment: Thats how we do it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23930728/aegis-mapping-not-working